# ESLint error on !string condition in a React JSX element

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I get an ESLint error from the statement: disabled={!input} (see below)

Here's how I define input:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState<string>("");
```

Snippet:

```
    <button
      disabled={!input}
      className="rounded-full font-bold py-2 px-5 text-white disabled:opacity-40"
    >
      Tweet
    </button>
```

Since input is a string, what's the correct way to pass ESLint checks. If string is empty, null, or undefined, disable the button.

I could create a function to do this, but there's got to be an easier way given the eloquent simplicity of !input.

The only thing that appears to work is the following snippet:

```
disabled={input === "" || input === null || input === undefined}
```

But is there an easier, more concise way?

Comment: You can explicitly convert `!input` it to a boolean value using the double negation operator: `!!input`. In your case you would want to put `!!!input`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same ESLint fail.

Comment: Which eslint rule exactly are you getting the error from?

Comment: You can use the `Boolean(input)` function to type cast it to one. Looks cleaner and easy to read. You may also use `input?.trim() !== ''`

Comment: I like the input?.trim() === "" solution

Comment: rule: eslint@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions

Comment: I need the inverse of Boolean(input) and !Boolean(input) fails as does Boolean(input) === false

Comment: Here is the doc for this linting rule: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/strict-boolean-expressions/. You could simply disable it if you don't like it. It's neither part of the strict or the recommended set of rules. Or you could configure it to allow strings.